# insert not exist duplicando registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

tou com um problema no SQL server 2008
tenho que inserir uma ocorrência dos dados de cartão de credito contudo a consulta não está ocorrendo do jeito que eu precisava.
As tabelas são

```
  CREATE TABLE TEMP_DADOS_CARTAO
        (
            TOKENID_PARCELA     VARCHAR(255)
          , CARDNUMBER     VARCHAR(255)
          , HOLDER         VARCHAR(255)
          , EXPIRATIONDATE VARCHAR(255)
          , ARQUIVO_LOG    VARCHAR(100)
        )
    ;

CREATE TABLE DADOS_CARTAO (
    ID int  IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    TOKENID_PARCELA varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
    TOKENID varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
    CARDNUMBER varchar(255) NULL,
    HOLDER varchar(250)  NULL,
    EXPIRATIONDATE varchar(7)  NULL,
    DATA_PROCESSAMENTO datetime2(7) NULL,
    ARQUIVO_LOG varchar(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DADOS_CARTAO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

tanto o insert into not exist  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0b83/1

```
INSERT INTO DADOS_CARTAO
        (TOKENID_PARCELA
          , TOKENID
          , CARDNUMBER
          , HOLDER
          , EXPIRATIONDATE
          , DATA_PROCESSAMENTO
          , ARQUIVO_LOG
        )
    SELECT
        TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA
      , SUBSTRING(TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA, 1, 25)
      , TEMP.CARDNUMBER
      , TEMP.HOLDER
      , TEMP.EXPIRATIONDATE
      , GETDATE()
      , TEMP.ARQUIVO_LOG
    FROM
        TEMP_DADOS_CARTAO TEMP
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
            FROM
                DADOS_CARTAO EC
            WHERE
                EC.TOKENID =SUBSTRING(TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA, 1, 25)
        )
```

quanto o merge http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b90b/1

```
MERGE DADOS_CARTAO as DC
    USING (SELECT
        T.TOKENID_PARCELA  , SUBSTRING(T.TOKENID_PARCELA, 1, 25) TOKENID, T.CARDNUMBER , T.HOLDER  , T.EXPIRATIONDATE ,T.ARQUIVO_LOG
        from TEMP_DADOS_CARTAO T ) as TEMP 
    on DC.TOKENID =TEMP.TOKENID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (TOKENID_PARCELA
          , TOKENID
          , CARDNUMBER
          , HOLDER
          , EXPIRATIONDATE
          , DATA_PROCESSAMENTO
          , ARQUIVO_LOG)
    VALUES (TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA
      , TEMP.TOKENID
      , TEMP.CARDNUMBER
      , TEMP.HOLDER
      , TEMP.EXPIRATIONDATE
      , GETDATE()
      , TEMP.ARQUIVO_LOG);;
```

estão duplicando os registros

não sei o que estou fazendo de errado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olha, na sua tabela temporária você tem `1:N`.
Ou seja, cada `TokenId` pode aparecer várias vezes.

Se você quer inseri-los somente uma vez, poderia agrupar os dados, pegando o ultimo registro de cada um.

O fato é que mesmo o `MERGE` e o `INSERT NOT EXISTS`, vão acabar inserindo exatamente o que retorna no seu `JOIN`.

Se você testar aquele `INSERT NOT EXISTS`, sem a parte do `INSERT`, vai ver que ali já está trazendo os dados duplicados... E eles não serão validados linha a linha durante o `INSERT`... É por isso que os dados acabam sendo inseridos de forma duplicada.

Como sugestão, eu diria pra agrupar os dados, mas não sei se é isso que você esta realmente querendo fazer.

Exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO DADOS_CARTAO
        (TOKENID_PARCELA
          , TOKENID
          , CARDNUMBER
          , HOLDER
          , EXPIRATIONDATE
          , DATA_PROCESSAMENTO
          , ARQUIVO_LOG
        )
    SELECT
        TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA
      , SUBSTRING(TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA, 1, 25)
      , TEMP.CARDNUMBER
      , TEMP.HOLDER
      , max(TEMP.EXPIRATIONDATE)
      , GETDATE()
      , max(TEMP.ARQUIVO_LOG)
    FROM
        TEMP_DADOS_CARTAO TEMP
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
            FROM
                DADOS_CARTAO EC
            WHERE
                EC.TOKENID =SUBSTRING(TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA, 1, 25)
                /*se os dados já forem cadastrados, não cadastra novamente*/
        )
        group by TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA
      , SUBSTRING(TEMP.TOKENID_PARCELA, 1, 25)
      , TEMP.CARDNUMBER
      , TEMP.HOLDER
```

Veja rodando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9dd61/1).

Comment: hummm então ele faz o select todo antes do insert, achei que pra cada insert ele iria verificar o "WHERE  NOT EXISTS"